# Child divs not recognizing all properties of parent div, not aligning to parent

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to code a blog page with a header, a navigation, a left sidebar, a right sidebar, and content. All of these sections are child divs being wrapped in an outer div. However, not all the properties of the parent div are being recognized, and `bgSide` is appearing overtop of the wrapper instead of underneath it and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I do not have any floats and I have already run my code through a program to ensure there's nothing wrong with the markup. `overflow: hidden` does nothing.

**UPDATE ONE:** Solved width property not inheriting. Still need solutions for wrapper height not working, left and right aligning to body instead of wrapper, and image showing up on top instead of behind.

**UPDATE TWO:** Solved height property not working by changing `height: 100%;` to `height: 100vh;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    background:{color:background};
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: url('{image:background}');
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#bgside img
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper
{
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0px auto; /* center the body */
    padding: 0px;

    border: 1px solid {color:side link border};
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;

    text-align: center;
    background: {color:background};

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px #000
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 20px #000;
}

#header
{
    background: {color:header background};
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0px;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid {color:side link border};
    border-width: 0px 1px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#header img
{
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

#nav
{
    background: {color:navigation background};
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 100px;
    width: 60%;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
    border: 1px solid {color:side link border}; 

    text-align:center;
    line-height:5px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
}

#nav a
{
    background: {color:top link bg};
    padding: 2px 15px 3px 15px;
    margin: 4px;

    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: {color:top link text};

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#nav a:hover
{
    color:{color:top link text hover};
    background:{color:top link bg hover};
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#right
{
    background: {color:sidebar background};
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 135px;
    right: 0px;

    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: center;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
}

#left
{
    background: {color:sidebar background};
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 135px;
    left: 0px;

    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: center;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000;
}

#content
{
    /* Not coded yet */
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="bgside"><img src="{image:bgside}" alt="bgSide"/></div>

    <!-- START OF CONTAINER -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id= "header"><img src="{image:header}" alt="header"/></div>

        <div id= "nav">
            A BUNCH OF LINKS
        </div>

        <div id="left">
            CONTENT
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            CONTENT            
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            CONTENT
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- END OF CONTAINER -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try to use inherit for things that don't cascade, for example. width:inherit; background:inherit;

Comment: Thank you foreyez, that solves the inheritance of the width properties.

Comment: You can try the CSS rule: `all: inherit;`

Comment: Also, add: `html, body {height: auto;}` to make sure that heights work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTIONS:**

**Width property not inheriting:**

Change `width` properties of `#nav` and `#header` to `width: inherit;`

**Height property not being recognized in wrapper:**

In wrapper CSS, change `height: 100%;` to `height: 100vh;`

**Left and Right ignoring wrapper and aligning to body:**

Remove this code:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
top: 135px;
right: 0px;
```

and replace with `float: right;` and do the same with `#left` while assigning left instead of right. Then add `overflow: hidden;` to `#wrapper`

**bgside ignoring z-index and layering on top:**

Change `z-index: 0;` to `z-index: -1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding inherit to things inside the wrap that don't cascade. Some programs do this for you. For example:

```
height:inherit;
background:inherit;
color:inherit;
```

This may take a while but it works for me!

Comment: Sorry foreyez I wrote this before I saw that comment!